# How to create HashMaps in javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

My question is instead of inheriting the array prototype
Is there some way we can manipulate associative arrays to use them as Hashmaps with functions like `getKey`,`getValue`,`ContainsKey`,`ContainsValue`?

Comment: JavaScript is not PHP, there are no "associative arrays". You can use objects or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Map` class that Javascript provides:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set("key", 23);
console.log(map.get("key")); // 23
console.log(map.has("key")); // true
```

An alternative that works as well and is kinda a basic concept of Javascript are normal `Objects` since they behave like maps. Eventhough you can use normal objects, I recommend using `Map`.

```js
const obj = {
  "key": 23
}

console.log(obj["key"]); // 23

obj["another key"] = 420;

console.log(obj["another key"]); // 420

// and the ugly version of Map.has:
console.log(obj["key"] !== undefined); // true
```